# Trying to format textbox value in a something like money

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to show on a textbox a value like money exemple: 10.50. But everytime i put 10.50 its show 10.5

```
    Private Sub button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As
            System.EventArgs) Handles button1.Click

       textbox3.text = val(textbox1.text) + val(textbox2.text)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use format string.

```
textbox3.text = (val(textbox1.text) + val(textbox2.text)).ToString("N")
```

I'd like to suggest `Decimal.TryParse` method instead of `val()` function.

```
Dim no1,no2,no3 as Decimal
Decimal.TryParse(TextBox1.Text,no1)
Decimal.TryParse(TextBox2.Text,no2)

no3= no1 + no2

TextBox3.Text= no3.ToString("N")
```

Comment: i can't cause i will use to calculate it again late

Comment: @RaphaelFernandes that's not a good reason. The .Text property of a textbox **is a string**. When you assign a value to it, conversion to string **will** happen ...unless you have option strict on (and you should), in which case you'll get an exception. Also, I advise against using the `Val()` function. Look at either one of the conversion operaters ie: CInt, CStr, CDec, the Convert.To_() functions, or the Parse/TryParse() functions (ie: Decimal.TryParse())

Answer (score 1):

So why don't you just use an NumericUpDown instead? 
You can set it to have two decimal places using

```
NumericUpDownCtrlName.DecimalPlaces = 2
```

To get or set the value which is a decimal simply use:

```
NumericUpDownCtrlName.Value
```